# How to make every combination of colors with pil?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to make some combinations from different palettes, so I need to create for every color from palette webhexred with every color from palette webhexyel. I would like to change colors on this image.
How can I do this?

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('AGXCL.jpg')

imnp = np.array(im)

webhexred = {
    "lightsalmon" : "#FFA07A",
    "salmon" :"#FA8072",
    "darksalmon" : "#E9967A",
    "lightcoral" : "#F08080"
    }
webhexyel = {
    "goldenrod" : "#DAA520",
    "gold": "#FFD700",
    "orange" : "#FFA500",
    "darkorange" : "#FF8C00"
}

output.save( webhexred + "_" + webhexyel + ".png")
```

Comment: As this should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please can you include the necessary code for what the `output` variable is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need numpy, and you don't need an input image.  Use a nested loop to run through both lists.  Create a new image, filled with one color, then use `ImageDraw` to draw the other color.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

webhexred = {
    "lightsalmon" : "#FFA07A",
    "salmon" :"#FA8072",
    "darksalmon" : "#E9967A",
    "lightcoral" : "#F08080"
    }
webhexyel = {
    "goldenrod" : "#DAA520",
    "gold": "#FFD700",
    "orange" : "#FFA500",
    "darkorange" : "#FF8C00"
}

for topname,top in webhexred.items():
    for botname,bot in webhexyel.items():
        output = Image.new('RGB', (256,256), top)
        dc = ImageDraw.Draw(output)
        dc.rectangle( ((0,128),(256,256)), bot, bot)
        output.save( topname + "_" + botname + ".png")
```

Comment: I didn't know that PIL could work directly with hex color strings, that simplifies things tremendously.